# How to get the value of input type checkbox in RepeaterItems (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

i have button delete message from database but i cant get value from checked checkbox in repeateritem. how can i do that?
this my btndelete:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in rptInbox.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)aItem.FindControl("chkRow");

        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            string id = chk.Value.ToString();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from mailbox where mailboxid='"+id+"'", con);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this my html:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInbox" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ID="chkRow" value='<%#Eval("mailboxid")%>' runat="server"/></td>
            <td><%#Eval("from") %></td>
            <td><a href="InboxDetail.aspx?MailboxId=<%#Eval("mailboxid") %>"><%#Eval("subject") %></a></td>
            <td><%#Eval("date") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a hidden field:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptInbox" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ID="chkRow" runat="server"/>
                <input type="hidden" ID="hiddenMailBoxID" value='<%# Eval("mailboxid") %>' runat="server"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("from") %>
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And retrieve it in code-behind:

```
HtmlInputHidden hiddenMailBoxID = aItem.FindControl("hiddenMailBoxID") as HtmlInputHidden;
string id = hiddenMailBoxID.Value;
```